# Best Mocking Library

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mocking

Which is the best mocking library for C# 3.0/ ASP.NET MVC? Why?

Comment: You should clarify the language you want to use as well as what you understand as mocking.

Comment: Yes, you need to be more specific...this website is language and platform agnostic.

Comment: Clarification was added, so the negative votes should be removed IMHO.

Answer (score 21):

[Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4)

It's amazing, fully supports the new language features of C# 3.0 and it's very easy to get going with.  I would highly recommend it.

Comment: +1: Moq is a low-entry-barrier option.

Comment: Does not support UWP =(

Answer (score 8):

Very subjective question.  What do you mean by "best"?  Maybe you should provide some more context on your situation.

[RhinoMocks](http://www.ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx) is one of the most popular, as to whether it's the best for you, who knows?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going through that process now, weighing them up for use by my team, and I have to say Moq as well, it seems to have the least of a learning curve, and some nice features, I love the use of Moq generics to specify a Mock class

Answer (score 0):

there's also this other post about this topic:

[Best mock framework that can do both WebForms and MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10098/best-mock-framework-that-can-do-both-webforms-and-mvc)