# Refactor for Unit Testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I've been having a little trouble writing Unit Tests for my Business Logic layer, please point me in the right direction. Any advice would be appreciated.

**Business Logic**

```
public class TitleLogic
{
    private readonly TitleDAL titleDAL = new TitleDAL();
    private readonly List<TitleEntity> titleEntities;

    public TitleLogic()
    {
        titleEntities = titleDAL.GetAllTitles().ToList();
    }

    public TitleEntity InsertTitle(TitleEntity titleEntity)
    {
        if (!titleEntity.IsValid)
        {
            throw new EntityException<TitleEntity>("Invalid Title.", titleEntity);
        }

        titleEntity.TitleName.TrimSize(TitleEntity.TitleName_Length);

        var createdTitle = titleDAL.InsertTitle(titleEntity);

        titleEntities.Add(createdTitle);

        return createdTitle;
    }

    public TitleEntity FindTitle(string titleName)
    {
        return titleEntities.Find(p => p.TitleName == titleName);
    }
}
```

**Data Layer**

```
public class TitleDAL
{
    private readonly NLog.Logger logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public TitleEntity InsertTitle(TitleEntity titleEntity)
    {
        XTime900Entities xTime900Entities = new XTime900Entities();

        //Find the next CodeId to use
        var titleCodeId = xTime900Entities.TITLEs.Max(p => p.TITLE_CODEID) + 1;

        TITLE title = new TITLE
        {
            TITLE_CODEID = (short) titleCodeId,
            TITLE_ACTIVE = Convert.ToInt16(titleEntity.TitleActive),
            TITLE_NAME = titleEntity.TitleName
        };

        xTime900Entities.TITLEs.InsertOnSubmit(title);
        xTime900Entities.SubmitChanges();
        logger.Debug("Inserted New Title CodeId: {0}", titleCodeId);
        xTime900Entities.Dispose();

        return titleEntity.Clone((short)titleCodeId);
    }

    public ICollection<TitleEntity> GetAllTitles()
    {
        logger.Debug("Retrieving List all Titles from XTime900 database.");
        List<TitleEntity> titleEntities = new List<TitleEntity>();

        using (XTime900Entities XTEntities = new XTime900Entities())
        {
            var titlesInDB = from p in XTEntities.TITLEs
                                  select p;

            foreach (var titlesInDb in titlesInDB)
            {
                TitleEntity genderEntity = new TitleEntity(titlesInDb.TITLE_CODEID)
                {
                    TitleActive = Convert.ToBoolean(titlesInDb.TITLE_ACTIVE),
                    TitleName = titlesInDb.TITLE_NAME
                };

                titleEntities.Add(genderEntity);
            }
        }

        logger.Debug("Found {0} Titles.", titleEntities.Count);
        return titleEntities;
    }
}
```

**Entity**

```
public class TitleEntity
{
    public const int TitleName_Length = 30;

    public short TitleCodeId { get; private set; }
    public bool TitleActive { get; set; }
    public string TitleName { get; set; }
    public bool IsValid
    {
        get
        {
            return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(TitleName);
        }
    }

    public TitleEntity()
    {
        this.TitleCodeId = -1;
    }
    public TitleEntity(short titleCodeId)
    {
        this.TitleCodeId = titleCodeId;
    }

    public TitleEntity Clone(short titleCodeId)
    {
        TitleEntity genderEntity = new TitleEntity(titleCodeId)
        {
            TitleActive = this.TitleActive,
            TitleName = this.TitleName
        };

        return genderEntity;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine(String.Format("TitleCodeId : {0}", TitleCodeId));
        sb.AppendLine(String.Format("TitleActive : {0}", TitleActive));
        sb.AppendLine(String.Format("TitleName : {0}", TitleName));
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public static bool operator ==(TitleEntity x, TitleEntity y)
    {
        return (x.Equals(y));
    }

    public static bool operator !=(TitleEntity x, TitleEntity y)
    {
        return !(x.Equals(y));
    }

    public bool Equals(TitleEntity other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        return other.TitleCodeId == TitleCodeId && other.TitleActive.Equals(TitleActive) && Equals(other.TitleName, TitleName);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        return obj.GetType() == typeof(TitleEntity) && Equals((TitleEntity)obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            var result = TitleCodeId.GetHashCode();
            result = (result * 397) ^ TitleActive.GetHashCode();
            result = (result * 397) ^ (TitleName != null ? TitleName.GetHashCode() : 0);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't easily test your business logic as you have created your DAL component inside your `TitleLogic` class.

First thing I would do is make `TitleDAL` implement an `ITitleDAL` interface and make `TitleLogic` class take an instance of `ITitleDAL` interface.

Then when you are testing the `InsertTitle` method you can have tests which:

- check that when an invalid `TitleEntity` is given the `EntityException` is thrown
- When the entity is valid that `ITitleDAL.InsertTitle` is called.
- When a title is correctly inserted, it can be found using the `FindTitle` method

In your tests you will need to create a mock `ITitleDAL` implementation (or use a [mocking library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80067/best-mocking-library) to create one for you) so that your tests return known expected data are not dependent on the actual DAL.

you might also want to consider testing for:

- What happens if the `InsertTitle` method on `ITitleDAL` fails?

Comment: +1, same as I was writing with a much better structure/explanation ratio.

Comment: Great, this is more or less what I aiming for. Just one other q, should I then change "private readonly TitleDAL titleDAL = new TitleDAL();" to be public ITitleDAL titleDAL {get;set;} or pass it through in the constructor?

Comment: I think you should pass it through the constructor.  And you should not make the property public I don't think.  if the dependency is optional then you could have a property, which may or may not be set.  In this case the dependency is compulsory, so you should show that by asking for it in the constructor.

Comment: True. True. Thanks again for the help. Much appriciated.

Answer (score 2):

First thing you need to do is to think about dependency injection.  The simplest way for this to work would be to implement an interface for the DAL, along the lines of

```
interface ITitleDAL
{
    TitleEntity InsertTitle(TitleEntity titleEntity);
    ICollection<TitleEntity> GetAllTitles();
}
```

then make your DAL layer implement the interface.

Next, change the constructor for your DAL to accept an object that implements that interface...

```
public TitleLogic(ITitleDAL myDAL)
{
    titleDAL = myDAL;
    titleEntities = titleDAL.GetAllTitles().ToList();
}
```

Then create a mock version of your DAL that also implements the interface, but returns static data.

After that, you need to do 2 things.

1) Make your production code create the DAL instance and pass it into the constructor of your business layer.
2) Make your unit test pass in an instance of your mocked class to the constructor, and test against the known data you have coded.

Comment: Please note that this answer is intended as a starting point, giving a quick reference to the way to go forward, and deliberately doesn't talk about mocks / stubs / mocking frameworks or any of that glorious stuff.  Simple first steps... :)

Comment: +1 for examples, and for giving a breakdown of the simplest things that will work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have one question though, I also have and EmployeeLogic which has TitleLogic, GenderLogic, OccupationLogic, DepartmentLogic, TeamLogic etc. Is this not too many parameters to pass though the contructor?

Comment: I see your concern about too many parameters, but aren't you using separate business layers for each? (a decision I can't criticise without seeing the whole of your app, but feels wrong somehow)  In that case, you're creating one IDataLayer for each so your constructors would only take one each...

Answer (score 0):

You want to test each type in isolation. That is, when you write tests for your business objects you don't want to be forced to exercise the code for the DAL and helper objects that it uses (like XTime900Entities, etc).

Right now, all these types are tightly coupled to eachother, which is unnecessary and is a problem from a testability perspective. That is, a unit test for your business object class is forced to be coupled to your data access layer and implementation. That won't work in the long run. It wont scale over a large code base and unit test maintenance will skyrocket over change.

Also, you need to take exceptions into concern here. For instance, xTime900Entities.Dispose(); will not be called if there is an exception in the middle of that method. This means that your code will be leaking resources if something unexpected happens during InsertTitle. It is a general concept, but something like this would be better in this case:

XTime900Entities xTime900Entities = new XTime900Entities()
{
   // rest of method
} // dispose called here automatically, regardless if an exception is thrown in the block or not

Good practices is injecting dependencies, depend on abstractions, to isolate concerns, which allows you to test in isolation.

Comment: Oops, I forgot to change XTime900Entities to a using statement, I agree with that. The reason I didn't have it in a using statement was cause originally I though if you return within using statement the finally doesn't get called, I then found out it is always called. I do test my Entites, and Logic, my DAL doesn't really need to be tested I guess. I unsderstand that the DAL is tightly coupled with Business logic in a sense, and hence my qyestion for Testing, maybe implementing ITilteDAL to get around the Issue but other then that I think this seperation of layers is a good design.